# How to format a bokeh DataTable cell based on another column value with Column Value from Data Source containing a space?

Tags: python, bokeh

I need some help with using HTMLTemplateFormatter for a DataTable.
When defining a template argument to HTMLTemplateFormater, I am trying to use a conditional statement as:

```
    template="""                
            <p style="color:<%= 
                (function colorfromimp(){
                    if ((Column Name=='A1')) // variable name
                        {return('red')}
                    }()) %>;"> 
                <%= value %>
            </p>
            """
    formatter =  HTMLTemplateFormatter(template=template)
```

Using Column Name to update column values in a DataTable. However, it seems like Column Name cannot have spaces. Is there a way to escape the space, I tried with a lower case column and it worked.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try using the `<pre><%= value %></pre>` formatting?

Comment: I just tried the following, seems like it is not escaping the Column Name. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand what "Column Name" is here, or where it came from. Typically, you would compare a *variable* against some value, e.g. "A1". But "Column Name" is not a valid variable name in either Python or JS, so the code above does not make sense to me. It would be more helpful if you provide a small *complete* example, so that people trying to help can actually run things themselves.

Comment: "Column Name" comes from a pandas dataframe reading in a local csv for testing purposes. # Columns of table
 table_columns = [
 TableColumn(field="Column A", title="Column A"),
 TableColumn(field="Column B", title="Column B", formatter=formatter), 
 ]
Column A serves as a placeholder for an arbitrary field name that includes spaces. I could overcome this with making an inplace update to Column Name with df['column_name'] = df['Column Name']. Just trying to see if there is a solution to avoid an explicit change to the dataframe prior to rendering to the browser. Thanks in advance!